# How to render table width automatically based on reactGridLayout change?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, grid-layout, ag-grid

[image: layout image]I am using ResponsiveReactGridLayout for resizing of paper component, but after resize i cannot able to resize the AGGrid table same as layout change width

I tried with below code and onchange of layout table is not resizing fully

```
            <ResponsiveReactGridLayout 
               layouts={this.state.layout} 
               onLayoutChange={this.onLayoutChange}
               className={this.state.className}            
                rowHeight={this.state.rowHeight}
                cols={this.state.cols}
                initialLayout= {this.state.layout}
                initialWidth={this.state.initialWidth}
                width={this.state.width}
                verticalCompact={false}
                listenToWindowResize={false}
                currentBreakpoint= 'sm'
                >
              {this.state.response && this.state.response.data && this.state.response.data.map((data, i) => 
                <Paper id='resizer' key={i} className="paper_panel">
                    <div style={containerStyle} className="ag-blue">
                    <AgGridReact
                        columnDefs={this.createHeader()}
                        rowData={this.tableData()}
                        onGridReady={this.onGridReady}
                        enableFilter
                        enableSorting>
                    </AgGridReact>
                    </div>


                </Paper>
              )} 
            </ResponsiveReactGridLayout>



            let containerStyle = {
              height:300,
              width: 500
          };
```

I need to get table to be resized according to the layout change

Comment: `gridOptions.api.sizeColumnsToFit();`

Comment: as i kept width as 500 in container style, it is not changing if i remove containerStyle style then nothing is dsplaying,

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi

I kept but it is only for fitting to particular width, but width need be resized after layout change